# Check if one json value is in the json value from another JSON, for each key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, compare

With SQL in postgres, I want to know if one JSON is 'IN' another JSON.

For example:

```
json_1 = {"a": ["123"], "b": ["456", "789"]}
json_2 = {"a": ["123"], "b": ["456"]}
```

In the above case, json_2["a"] is in json_1["a"] and json_2["b"] is in json_1["b"].

If I would know all the possible keys of the json, I would easily be able to write the above per key. However, the problem is that I don't know how many and which keys are in the JSON. How can I check for every key in the JSON, if json_2 is in json_1?

Comment: So json_1/2 can contain any number of keys with any names, and each of those keys will always be an array, and for each array in json_2, you want to check the corresponding key (which may not exist) in json_1, and then see if all the values from the json_2 array are found in the json_1 array in any order?

Comment: Correct. However, if the key is in json_2, I do know it also will be in json_1. So the 'may not exist' part doesn't hold. However, the value of the key in json_1 could be [] then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what output format you want, but this will create one row per key, with a boolean stating whether the json_2 key's array values are contained within the json_1 key's values.

```
CREATE TABLE t (json_1 JSONB, json_2 JSONB);
INSERT INTO t
VALUES
    ('{"a":["123"],"b":["456","789","aaa"],"c":["999"],"d":[]}',
     '{"a":["123"],"b":["789","456"],"c":["123"],"d":["x"]}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT key, value <@ (json_1->key) AS contained
FROM (
  SELECT (JSONB_EACH(json_2)).*, json_1
  FROM t
) j;
```

Returns:

```
| key | contained |
| --- | --------- |
| a   | true      |
| b   | true      |
| c   | false     |
| d   | false     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ehXASqxeHdRituBogke5U/0)